# How to express/write a permutation of a Set?

Tags: permutations

How to express a permutation (without repetition) of a Set $A$?

I'd like to create a set $P$ of tuples while equal tuples should only occur once in the set $P$. Tuples are equal when e.g. $\{a, b\} = \{b, a\}$. Tuples of the same values should not be included, e.g. $\{a, a\}$.

Example: Given $A = \{a, b, c\}$, I would like to receive $P = \{\{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, \{b, c\}\}$.

How can I write this in an equation?

Comment: Can you define exactly what you mean by permutation, the word has acquired several different meanings (though it has one that is more prevalent, and appears to *not* be what are interested in).

Comment: I'd like to create a set $P$ of tuples while equal tuples should only occur once in the set $P$. Tuples are equal when e.g. $\{x, y\} = \{y, x\}$. For example: Given $A = \{a, b, c\}$, I would like to receive $P = \{\{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, \{b, c\}\}$.

Comment: I am still unclear what the question means despite reading the accepted answer. The answer appears to give you the set of all subsets of $A$ with 1 or 2 elements. But you give two examples in your question which do not fit that. The first has only two of the $n$ possible subsets with one element and with only $n-1$ of the possible $\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)$ possible subsets with 2 elements. Your second example suggests $P$ is unique given $A$ but only gives subsets with 2 elements. Please explain further what you want.

Comment: Hi @almagest, I've edited my question. Hopefully it's more clear now. I've never really used math that way until a few weeks ago and English is not my first language. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Hi @ThomasZuberbühler I thought there might be a language issue and I was worried by the two votes to close (on the basis that the question is unclear). Some people on this site are trigger-happy when it comes to voting to close :) "Permutations" is definitely the wrong word in this context. I think what you want is the set of ALL subsets of $A$ with two elements. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct. :) Is there a term for such a subset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A concise description of the sets you seek, using set builder notation, are:

$P=\{\{a,b\}:a,b\in A\}$

$P^{\prime}=\{\{a,b\}:a\neq b\textrm{ and }a,b\in A\}$

Edit: In light of comments since posting this, the set you desire appears to be $P^{\prime}$ above, which can also be described as in user3313320's answer.

Comment: Note that an 'pair' $\{a,a\}$ actually simplifies to $\{a\}$.

Comment: See the last few comments under the question.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be an $n$-element set.  The set of all $2$-element subsets of $A$ is the set $A^{\{2\}} := \{ B \subseteq A: |B| = 2\} = \{ \{a,b\}: a, b \in A, a \ne b \}$.  The cardinality of this set is ${n \choose 2}$.   But this set does not contain $2$-subsets of the form $\{a,a\}$ which contain repeated elements.

If you want to repeat elements, the objects you are interested in are called  multisets.  The multisets $\{a_1,a_1,a_2\}$ and $\{a_1,a_2\}$ are distinct (and have cardinalities $3$ and $2$, respectively), although these two multisets are the same set.  What you are looking for then is the set of all multisets of $A$ of cardinality $2$.

Answer (score 0):

$P=\{C|C\subset A \text{ and }|C|=2\}$ should work.

In words, it is the set of all subset of $A$ with two elements.